# Filter Chosen drop down by group selected by another drop down (using JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I have an ASP.NET MVC program which contains two drop down lists, Countries and Locations.
Both are populated from SelectLists stored in the ViewBag.

What I would like to do is filter the Locations by group (Countries) when that country is selected in the first drop down list.
(Either by telling the program to hide options that aren't in that group, or somehow auto-populating the Chosen search bar with the group?)

I have tried various solutions, but can't quite get it to work.

This is an attempt that I have based off of another potential solution online:

```
        $("#Countries").on('change', function (evt, params) {
            var selected = params.selected;

            //var optGroup = $('optgroup[label="' + selected + '"]')[0].outerHTML;
            var optGroup = $('optgroup[label="' + selected + '"]').html();
            $("#Locations").html(optGroup);
            $("#Locations").trigger("chosen:updated");

        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT**
I have gotten this solution to work, however it replaces the locations' list so I cannot filter a second time.

**EDIT2**
These are the two lines from the controller which store the data into the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.Countries = new MultiSelectList(db.tblCountries, "CountryID", "CountryName");
ViewBag.Locations = new MultiSelectList(db.tblLocations, "LocationID", "LocationName", "tblCountry.CountryName");
```

If you know of any alternative methods to solve this, please post below.

 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just empty before you bind html again:

```
 $("#Countries").on('change', function (evt, params) {
        var selected = params.selected;

        //var optGroup = $('optgroup[label="' + selected + '"]')[0].outerHTML;
        var optGroup = $('optgroup[label="' + selected + '"]').html();
        $("#Locations").empty();
        $("#Locations").html(optGroup);
        $("#Locations").trigger("chosen:updated");

    });
```

Comment: This didn't work. It just emptied the locations' list and doesn't repopulate when I select another country. I may be because the list is initially bound using the ViewBag.

Comment: I get your requirement now. Right, because once you have updated the html you can't get the data to bind locations. Unless you save it some where.

Comment: Can you post properties you use to bind locations dropdown in view?